# Node.js API : best practice about log

Tags: node.js, api, express, server, winston

I'm developing a server under Node.js using Express and I use winston to log.

Is it a good practice to log every call to the API and every response to the call on the terminal ? Is it a good practice to log that in a log file too ? There could be up to 100 calls per second.

I'm talking here about info log, not error log.

Comment: Logging 100 calls per second isn't normally an issue, but I have no idea why you'd want that on a terminal. Displaying things on terminal will be slower than writing to a file, and there's nothing useful you can glean from hundreds of log messages just zipping past you.

Aside from technical problems, you should think about security/legal implications. Your API calls may contain sensitive data which needs to be protected for instance, and you never want to log things like plaintext passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a good practice for debugging when it comes under development phase. When it moved to the production you need to comment it out. If it logs for each and every request then it may affect the performance of the application. So you may use the logs for the critical pieces alone.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, some webservers log automatically every request (Nginx does for detault).

Is it a good practice? I would not do it in the situation you mentioned (100 calls per second).

A solution would be dumping to a file the logs every x times you have logged a new request. This way you would have to write your logs once every 100 times.